# Regex - Match only if input does not contain all letters

Tags: regex, surveyjs

I understand the regex used to match if it contains all letters is `^[a-zA-Z]+$` so I thought a negation of this regex would be the answer and tried `^(?!^[a-zA-Z])+$` but it doesn't seem to work.

To provide some context, I'm creating a basic form using SurveyJS form creator that accepts custom validation only via regex. A certain form input should allow users to input anything and only throw an error if the user only fill in letters.

Comment: I don't know Regex that much, but I just want to point out that you have visual tools to debug your regex! https://regex101.com/

Comment: Provide examples, please. Which inputs must be validated as good and which as bad.

Comment: `^(?!.*[A-Za-z]).*$` Here is the [visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5bqXLRis3VsTWj8j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+$).*
```

The negative lookahead ensures the whole line does not only contain `a-zA-Z` till the `$` (end of line - thats why its included *inside* the lookahead - not outside of it) and the `.*` afterwards would match anything that passes the negative lookahead.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QuC2SQ/1